# what kind of outdoor vent (for furnace) is this?

Tags: vent, venting

This is a vent for a home-heating furnace (blown-air, gas-heated).

There was some kind of plastic meshing on the outside. It's broken. Now I have to go very high up and fix this somehow. A scary prospect. Any idea if some ordinary meshing (I have some old used window meshing lying around) can be wrapped around this thing to make it work? Or do I need some specialized meshing? Would there be a way to fix this from inside the house (it's very high up from outside and I tried going up a ladder and got scared).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does it connect to on the inside?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact A house-heating furnace (blown-air, gas-heated). Do you need the brand name of the furnace?

Comment: The mesh on the outside is probably to prevent birds/bugs/animals from building nests and blocking it.  Your ladder does look to be too short for safe work on it.  If you can work from inside, should be able to push a mesh to the outside edge.

Comment: I mean more like a picture showing what type of pipe is connected and how it is connected. In a general sense there are two types - 80% (or less) = very hot exhaust, 90% (or more) = low temperature exhaust with concerns about condensate.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even see the ladder until @crip659 mentioned it! Yes, your ladder is _way_ too short! The top of the ladder should come to just below the area you want to work on. That way, you'll be several rungs down and can _lean into_ the ladder for comfort. The way that ladder is positioned, it looks like you were at or near the top rung and your body was flat against the wall - that's terrifying for _anyone_!

Comment: It'd be two rungs above and I'd work reaching around/underneath the ladder. FTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a "horizontal vent termination kit." A web search will turn up several options (but they all look like they're made by the same company!). Although you probably can't buy the external cover piece alone there's a fair chance that you could buy a whole new kit and use only the new cover piece mounted to your existing base plate. The base plate is likely not sealed to the wall or to the pipes anyway so it would be easy enough to install both new parts.

You'll need to figure out whether yours is 2 inch or 3 inch size.

Here's a representative photo from a Home Depot product listing:
[image: horizontal vent termination]

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that it's a concentric intake/exhaust termination, with the intake being behind the flange. Otherwise it's probably just exhaust. You'll have to investigate.

You could cut an octagon of 1/4" galvanized hardware cloth and flex it into the opening. Would be cleaner than wrapping the whole thing. That's how many come from the factory.

[image]